# all labels in form change properties when mouse focus

Tags: arrays, vb6, label

I want to simulate a game menu using labels. What I want to do is when a mouse hovers on it, the font will become bigger and it will change font color. Is there any preexisting code for doing this using just arrays in Visual Basic 6.0? Because if I do it manually, it will take lots of time. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to catch the mouse enter, and leave events. This is old, but you can try using the TrackMouseEvent API to catch the mouse events. Here is a link, http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Subclassing/Generating_MouseLeave_Events_for_a_Window/article.asp, with a class that implements the API, and gives an example of using it. The article is old though and only discusses its use up to Win 95 so you'll need to do a quick test to see if it's still supported.

Answer (score 0):

to create an array of labels : place a label on the form, and give it index 0
that will bascially create an array of 1 label, which you can then expand in your code

```
'1 form with :
'    1 label : name=Label1    Index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = 1 To 4
    Load Label1(intIndex)
    Label1(intIndex).Visible = True
    Label1(intIndex).Caption = CStr(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  OnLabel False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngLblWidth As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight
  sngLblWidth = sngWidth / Label1.Count
  For intIndex = 0 To Label1.Count - 1
    Label1(intIndex).Move intIndex * sngLblWidth, 0, sngLblWidth
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(Index As Integer, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  OnLabel True
End Sub

Private Sub OnLabel(blnOn As Boolean)
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim intSize As Integer
  Dim lngColor As Long
  If blnOn Then
    intSize = 20
    lngColor = vbRed
  Else
    intSize = 10
    lngColor = vbBlack
  End If
  For intIndex = 0 To Label1.Count - 1
    With Label1(intIndex)
      .FontSize = intSize
      .ForeColor = lngColor
    End With 'Label1(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```